# How to scan the entire Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to scan all my firebase, to make the following queries which I already researched in the documentation and did not find:

> **1)** I need to count how many shopping malls in the database.
>
> **2)** I need to get the Arrays of numbers from each mall so I can insert
>   into a ".push ()" function in google maps api and create the lat and
>   lng for each polygon.
>
> I'll explain how my firebase architecture will look:
>
> I have several "Shopping Center Administrators", which in this JSON
>   they call themselves (Aliansce, New Company).
>
> Within each Administrator Shopping Mall, I have several shopping malls
>   which are (Aliansce: Bangu, New York, ny2) and (New Company: luc2,
>   luc1).
>
> Within each Shopping, I have the ID's for each.
>
> Within the ID's I have the ID's dates.
>
> Inside the ID's date I have I have the store that contains in the
>   mall.

**FIREBASE DATABASE:**

```
{
  "aliansce" : {
    "AliansceShopping1" : {
      "1" : {
        "loja1" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ -33.564, -35.259, -35.155 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ 149.276, 148.705, 150.1 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "loja1"
        }
      },
      "2" : {
        "loja2" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ 2.258579, -59.008697, -55.493581, 13.727475 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ -95.338008, -82.330197, -14.127078, -37.857544 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "loja2"
        }
      }
    },
    "AliansceShopping2" : {
      "3" : {
        "loja1" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ -33.564, -35.259, -35.155 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ 149.276, 148.705, 150.1 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "Loja1"
        }
      },
      "4" : {
        "loja2" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ 2.258579, -59.008697, -55.493581, 13.727475 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ -95.338008, -82.330197, -14.127078, -37.857544 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "Loja2"
        }
      }
    },
    "versoes" : {
      "bangu" : {
        "190001" : "13/11/2017",
        "201701" : "13/11/2017",
        "201706" : "13/11/2017"
      }
    }
  },
  "novoAdm" : {
    "novoAdmShopping1" : {
      "1n" : {
        "loja1" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ -33.564, -35.259, -35.155 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ 149.276, 148.705, 150.1 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "loja1"
        }
      },
      "2n" : {
        "loja2" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ 2.258579, -59.008697, -55.493581, 13.727475 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ -95.338008, -82.330197, -14.127078, -37.857544 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "loja2"
        }
      }
    },
    "novoAdmShopping2" : {
      "3n" : {
        "loja1" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ -33.564, -35.259, -35.155 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ 149.276, 148.705, 150.1 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "Loja1"
        }
      },
      "4n" : {
        "loja2" : {
          "coordenadasLat" : [ 2.258579, -59.008697, -55.493581, 13.727475 ],
          "coordenadasLng" : [ -95.338008, -82.330197, -14.127078, -37.857544 ],
          "nomefantasia" : "Loja2"
        }
      }
    },
    "versoes" : {
      "nwVer" : {
        "190001" : "13/11/2017",
        "201701" : "13/11/2017",
        "201706" : "13/11/2017"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OBS: I'M USING JAVASCRIPT**

**CODE:**

```
function initFireBase(){
    var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/'); // INICIA NA RAIZ DO NÓ
    var rootDatabase = new Array();
    var childRootDatabase = new Array();
    var childParentDatabase = new Array();
    var tst;
    var tst2;


    ref.on('value', function(snap){
        // PERCORRE TODOS OS "CHILD'S" DO {REF}
        snap.forEach(function(rootSnapshot){
            rootDatabase = [...rootDatabase, rootSnapshot.key]; // CRIA UM ARRAY PARA AS "KEYS" DOS "CHILD'S"
        });

        for(a in rootDatabase){


                    tst = firebase.database().ref('' + rootDatabase[a]);

                    tst.on('child_added', function(snap){
                        snap.forEach(function(sna){
                            childRootDatabase = [...childRootDatabase, sna.key];
                        });
                    });

                    for(b in childRootDatabase){
                        tst2 = firebase.database().ref('/' + rootDatabase[a] + '/' + childRootDatabase[b]);
                        console.log(tst2.key);
                    }
        }



    });
```

**I was able to access all these children, but I can not get the coordinatesLat and lng;**

Comment: It is much more likely that somebody will help if you show what you've tried already. Not only does it show that you've made the effort, it also gives us a chance to understand where you are stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen look now man. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. But the code looks suboptimal, so hopefully an explanation of that will help you along.

Since you're loading the value from the root, there is no need to use any more nested listeners. Instead you can just iterate over the (nested) snapshots and get to the data you need. A more idiomatic way to do what your code currently does is:

```
ref.on('value', function(snap){
    mallKeys = [];
    snap.forEach(function(adminSnapshot){
        adminSnapshot.forEach(function(mallSnapshot) {
            mallKeys.push(mallSnapshot.key);
        });
    });
    console.log("There are "+mallKeys.length+" malls");
});
```

Comment: I would like to take all the values ​​of the Lat coordinates and coordinatesLng of the mall stores. My problem is this, I can not get there without being manually with the paths.

Comment: My code snippet shows how to loop two levels deep into your data structure without knowing the paths. If you need to go deeper into the tree, you'll need to add more nested loops.

Comment: Thank you, I've asked you a new question. If you can help thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383389/how-to-convert-array-from-datasnapshot-to-number-array#